# How to create "Buy in one click module"

Tags: magento2, php, database, ajax

I need help to add "Buy Now" button on the product detail page and on product list page.It not the same as "Add to cart" button, "Buy now" button should show popup which asked only phone number, it should sent to controller product_id and selected attributes and save to db.

In Instant Purchases it works in another way. Customer should be log in and fill shipment and payment info. In my case I need that even guest may buy in one click without filling shipment and payment info, just phone and that't it. Another words I should make an order programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.2 added this functionality by the name Instant Purchase. It is part of magento 2.2 core.

read more about this in the following link.

[Instant Purchase module](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/mrg/ce/instant-purchase/)